# Electromotive Force & Potential Difference?

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity

> The potential difference across the terminals of a battery is the work done per coulomb of charge in the external circuit. [1] The e.m.f. of a battery is the work done per coulomb of charge in the complete circuit

I've come across the definition above that explains the difference between the potential difference and the electromotive force. However, the definition above doesn't make much sense. It seems they define potential difference and e.m.f as the exact same which is not correct. Could someone elucidate what the explanation means?

Comment: It says PD is external circuit and EMF is complete circuit. I think this is a bad definition; just never use EMF because it is no longer an acceptable term to use.

Answer (score 2):

I think the text meant not that much to say that the definition of emf is the work done per coulomb of charge in the complete circuit, which includes both the external circuit and the internal circuit (which usually means the resistence of the battery itself), but rather it is equal to. The text is emphasizing that the quantitative difference between the potential difference across the terminals of a battery and the emf is whether the work done on the internal circuit is included.

Answer (score 2):

They are both potential differences (voltages). Potential difference, or voltage, is the umbrella term. Emf only applies to the open circuit (no load) potential difference between the terminals of an energy source (e.g. a battery).

Hope this helps.